# PHP Ignoring if/Else statement in registration script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on the login system on my site. Each user recieves a unique key on purchase that they then use to register on the site. Upon registration with the key it gets passed through a script that checks my database of keys to make sure it isn't in use already (if it passes that check, the key is marked "in use"). It then moves on to insert the user in the database, storing their key as well as their payment status as "sub".

My issue is that my script is completely ignoring the key check if/else block. It fails to change the in_use to "Y". It is also telling me registration successful even though the pay_status variable is not being passed to the final insert statement.

Was wondering if anyone could have a go at my php and see if there is anything obvious I am missing. Ignore the injectable points as I stripped the code down to get it functioning before I secure it again.

Heres the php:

```
<?php
include_once 'link_auth.php';
include_once 'link_global.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['regkey'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $regkey = $_POST['regkey'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }
     // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    //Check if the registration key is in use --> If so, close statement, if not, mark key as in_use = Y and add it to the user's account, set payment status from trial (if trial) to sub
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id, regkey, in_use FROM keylist WHERE regkey = '$regkey' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $keystatus = $stmt->fetch();
                if ($keystatus['in_use'] == 'N') {
                        //The key is available
                         $sql_updatekey = "UPDATE `keylist` SET in_use = 'Y' WHERE `regkey` = '$regkey'";
                         $pay_status = "sub";
                        $mysqli->query($sql_updatekey);
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">This key is already in use. If you feel this is an error, please contact support@hospitaldatasolutions.com</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, firstname, lastname, regkey, salt, payment_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $username, $email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $regkey, $random_salt, $pay_status);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: register_success.php');
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the correct result:

```
//Check if the registration key is in use --> If so, close statement, if not, mark key as in_use = Y and add it to the user's account, set payment status from trial (if trial) to sub
$prep_stmt = "SELECT regkey, active FROM keylist WHERE regkey = '$regkey' LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($col2,$col3);
    $keystatus = $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($col2,$col3);
            if ($keystatus && $col3=='N') {
                    //The key is available
                     $sql_updatekey = "UPDATE `keylist` SET active = 'Y' WHERE `regkey` = '$col2'";
                     $res=$mysqli->query($sql_updatekey);
                     $stmt->close();
            }
             else {
                    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">This key is already in use. If you feel this is an error, please contact support@hospitaldatasolutions.com</p>';
                    $stmt->close();
            }
}
```

The store_result() method is key as it frees up $mysqli to perform a new query. If there are still results waiting from the previous query, it will fail to perform the next. As of now my problem is completely solved. Both tables update with the necessary information.

Comment: What have you done to debug this so far?

Comment: Well, I can say that the code was fully functioning and working correctly before I added the block under "check if registration key is in use". So far I've just changed the statements/lines directly underneath it and just checked if the database updated in the correct fashion. I guess I was just wondering if there was something syntax wise that maybe was causing it to skip that block alltogether. After, if successful (it says it is), it goes to a registration success page which means that the $errmsg var was never filled by any of the other blocks. I'm new to this so not sure where to go rly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is logical error in if else part, I think els block for "key already used" is misplaced with if($stmt). I assume  your Keylist has in_use = 'N' for not used keys.

```
<?php
include_once 'link_auth.php';
include_once 'link_global.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['regkey'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $regkey = $_POST['regkey'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }
     // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    //Check if the registration key is in use --> If so, close statement, if not, mark key as in_use = Y and add it to the user's account, set payment status from trial (if trial) to sub
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id, regkey, in_use FROM keylist WHERE regkey = '$regkey' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2,$col3);
        $keystatus = $stmt->fetch();
                if ($keystatus && $col3=="N") {
                        //The key is available
                         $sql_updatekey = "UPDATE `keylist` SET in_use = 'Y' WHERE `regkey` = '$regkey'";
                         $pay_status = "sub";
                        $mysqli->query($sql_updatekey);
                        $stmt->close();
                }

                 else {
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">This key is already in use. If you feel this is an error, please contact support@hospitaldatasolutions.com</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
    }

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, firstname, lastname, regkey, salt, payment_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $username, $email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $regkey, $random_salt, $pay_status);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: register_success.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the table is filled in with N for all non-used keys. Will try your rework

Comment: ok now it's telling me the key is already in use when it isnt

Comment: Please add another line   var_dump($keystatus);   after  $keystatus = $stmt->fetch(); and send me the output so that i can find what is happening

Comment: I think $stmt->fetch() gives boolean, You need to store result to a variable using $stmt->bind_result() ? i have changed again, Hop it works but i haven't tested as i dont have data here

Comment: output says boolean true for the var dump I will also add bind result

Comment: I tried your code but it's still not updating the keylist in_use to Y. I'm not sure what to say about it I think I'm going to rename the column and see if it picks it up. the Vardump returns "null"

Comment: I had var_dump() in the wrong place and now it is returning the key and string 'N' from the database but something must be wrong with my update statement because the keylist still doesnt change from N to Y

Comment: echo $sql_updatekey; after $pay_status = "sub"; and copy printed sql, and run from phpMyAdmin? if command executes, Then This code mus be correct othere there will be an issue in query or table filed names etc

Comment: I echoed the query and it worked in mySQL, so I don't really know where to go from here...it's echoing from within the if statement so I know that the statement is now working. Should I make it a prepared statement and execute it maybe?

Comment: Yes, execute that statement as prepared by passing parameters. hope it works. Now $mysqli->query() is not executing. if you use like this you may find error

    if($res=$mysqli->query($sql_updatekey)) {
          echo("success");
    }
   else{
         echo($mysqli->error);
   }

Comment: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now is the error I got when I tried it

EDIT: Looks like I need to use $stmt->store_result(); in order to end the query and move onto he next one? can that be used alongside bind_result?

Comment: Yep that was exactly the problem. It turns out the previous query was still running as even though I had limited it to one result, there were still more possible rows to pull, therefore it was stuck in the previous query and preventing new ones from taking place. Store_result() stores the entire result set and frees the query up for a new statement. Thank you for all of your help! It's completely fixed and running perfect now!